# Debug Docker container with Visual Studio - application too fast?

Tags: visual-studio, docker, debugging

I want to debug an application within a Docker container as described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/edit-and-refresh?view=vs-2019

However, the application is *so* fast, that I'm always too late to attach me to the process. Is there a way to start the application in such a way that it breaks immediately? Or is there a way with Visual Studio to start the Docker container in such a way that it adds a breakpoint to the start of the Docker container's entry point?

Comment: Since you run in debug mode, I assume you can modify source code. Just add `Thread.Sleep` and have time to connect.

Comment: Yep, it's a possibility, and what I ended up with, hoped there is a better way - one that also works if you want to debug a live production system which cannot have any Thread.Sleeps in it ;-)

Comment: You generally can't debug in production anyway: 1) builds in Release mode 2) security restrictions, preventing connecting debugger and making proper dumps 3) lack of proper tools in prod environment. 4) `Thread.Sleep` won't be much slower than you stepping through functions step by step anyway